# Streamlit app's website (online) version does not redirect for google authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, backend, streamlit

I am trying to make an application with streamlit as frontend. My application involves taking user's google authentication, and thereby perform some actions based on the authentication. When my code is run locally, everything works fine, but there is an issue with the online version of the app: User is not redirected for authentication. When user clicks "Submit' first time, nothing happens (no matter how much time you wait), but when "Submit" is clicked on once more, there is an error, this is what appears on the Streamlit Log:

```
2023-10-07 14:55:10.154 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/mount/src/iiitd-timetable-googlecalendar/Main.py", line 159, in main

    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8888)

            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 499, in run_local_server

    local_server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server(

                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 154, in make_server

    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)

             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__

    self.server_bind()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind

    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind

    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socketserver.py", line 472, in server_bind

    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 541, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/mount/src/iiitd-timetable-googlecalendar/Main.py", line 182, in <module>

    main()

  File "/mount/src/iiitd-timetable-googlecalendar/Main.py", line 177, in main

    with open("Credentials/token.pickle", "r") as f:

         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Credentials/token.pickle'
```

I have used OAuth2.0 for the authentication. Although, I am not too sure whether the credentials are absolutely correct, the error thrown doesn't make sense. Here is a snippet of my code which deals with authentication:

```
submit = st.button("Submit")

    if submit:
        try:
            st.write("Authenticating...")
            creds = None
            if os.path.exists('Credentials/token.pickle'):
                with open('Credentials/token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                    creds = pickle.load(token)
            if not creds or not creds.valid:
                if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                    creds.refresh(Request())
                else:
                    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('Credentials/credentials.json', SCOPES)
                    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8888)
                with open('Credentials/token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                    pickle.dump(creds, token)
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request()) 
                with open('Credentials/token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                    pickle.dump(creds, token)      
                    
            gc = GoogleCalendar(credentials_path=cred_path, token_path=tok_path, save_token=True, read_only=False)
            
            st.write("Succesfully authenticated")
```

In code,

```
                    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8888)
```

i have tried using port = 0, port = 8080 too, but it didn't work.